# Scope issue: closed question is arguably in-scope

Tags: discussion

This question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/326504/how-to-code-review-obviously-plagiarized-code  was recently closed as being not-in-scope.

As I read the scope rules, "software engineering management" is in scope, and my reading of the question is that it's a management issue.

Where am I mistaken?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not on-topic. If you read the comments, the asker is in an academic setting. The primary tool used to make a decision here would be the university's academic honesty policies and the asker's relationship with the student. That's not within our scope. The things that we would be concerned with, such as licensing, would take a backseat to the university's policies.

Comment: You're correct, I should have read the comments.  Thanks.